# A number K and an Array of size N is given, check whether we can get the sum of any two elements of array equal to K

Tags: c++

I tried to solve the problem but my code still contains some bugs. Why isn't it running?

Here is the link of the question website:  https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/practice-problems/algorithm/pair-sums/?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;

    const int n = 1e7 + 10;
    int hsh[n];

    int main()
    {
        int n, k;
        cin >> n >> k;
        int A[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> A[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           hsh[A[i]] = k - A[i];
        }
        int t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (hsh[A[i]] == k - hsh[hsh[A[i]]])
            {
                cout << "YES";
                t = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (t == 0)
        {
            cout << "NO";
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you know about debugger exist for exactly the same reason? Trust me its perfect time to learn how to use a debugger. basically debugger help you run to your program step by step.

Comment: Why do you think `A[i]` is a valid index for the `hsh` array, as evidenced by expressions like `hsh[A[i]]`?  Also, you don't need `hsh`, just get rid of it.  Also, the fact that you named it `hsh` make me think you might be confused, because it's not a hash table.

Comment: @DavidGrayson These coding challenges often say in what range the input lies. So it could very well be that the input values are guaranteed to never exceed `1e7 + 9`. But there is much cringe in this code: the variable `n` is both a global and local variable, the use of the [non-standard `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)...

Comment: I'm surprised it even lets you make an array with ten million elements in it.

Comment: @David Grayson buddy you said A[is] is an invalid index, why do you think so? why can't it be? and Yes I kinda used the hash table method, but can't say it is a hash table,  is it wrong?

Comment: @G. Sliepen buddy, thanks for pointing out my syntactical error, I should've used block N instead of n for 1e7+10. But can you please help me with the logical error, cuz that's the main issue i am facing here.

Comment: @NathanPierson If it's a global variable it can basically be as large as you want and it will still compile. On Linux, when you try to execute it, it has to fit in RAM or else you get a segmentation fault. But 40 megabytes is not much these days.

Comment: A[i] could be negative or larger than n-1. If so, it would be an invalid index for that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that while `hsh[A[i]]` is always valid, `hsh[hsh[A[i]]` is not.
Consider the following input:

```
1 1
10000
```

This does the following:

```
A[0] = 10000;
...
hsh[10000] = 1 - 10000; // = -99999
...
if (hsh[10000] == 1 - hsh[-99999]) {...}
```

So your code is reading out of bounds of the array `hsh[]`. Make sure you check first if `hsh[A[i]] >= 0`.

Note that your code is more complicated than necessary; you can do a single loop over the input to check if there is a matching pair:

```
#include <iostream>

static constexpr int max_k = 2e6;
static bool seen[max_k + 1];

int main()
{
   int n, k;
   std::cin >> n >> k;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
     int A;
     std::cin >> A;

     if (A <= k && seen[k - A]) {
       std::cout << "YES\n";
       return 0;
     }

     seen[A] = true;
   }

   std::cout << "NO\n";
}
```